# save style to google spreadsheet

Tags: pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm writting dataframes to google spreadsheets with gspread_dataframe, gspread. I'm trying to assign a yellow background to cells depends on the values with pandas style. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html
Is there a way to save the assigned background color to the google spreadsheet too?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this one, you can use `gspread_formatting`

```
from gspread_formatting import *

bGYellow = cellFormat(backgroundColor=color(1, 1, 0))

format_cell_range(worksheet, 'A1:E1', bGYellow)
```

Please see [gspread-formatting](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/) for more details

Comment: thanks. is there a way to set the background color to be red if the absolute value of 1 or 2 columns are greater than certain values (eg, df.y.abs()>1,df.y.abs()>2)?  thanks

Comment: you need to loop all the values and then apply an `if` condition for each item, containing your conditions above. Inside that loop should be this after writing those data.

Comment: @user7264299, for the color red, you need to use `color(1, 0, 0)`. `color` accepts values 0 - 1 (including decimals in between as intermediary values) for `red`, `green` and `blue` for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd parameters respectively.

Comment: @user7264299, If you have additional questions that are outside the scope of your original question, kindly put it in another post. If your original question was already solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Would you please give an example how to apply an if condition to one column to high-light the cells in this column that meet the condition? thanks

Comment: style can be saved to excel. is it possible to save to google spreasheet?

Comment: @user7264299, saving style to google spreadsheet should be possible. For your additional questions, please put it in another post as it is not related with your original question and other users as well will be able to check your issue.

Comment: thanks. I tried to post a new question. however I was restricted to ask a new question. Maybe at most 1 question per day? do you have any idea how to save style to google spreadsheet? this is related to my original question.

Comment: @user7264299, see 4.1.15 in https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/gspread/latest/gspread.pdf

Comment: limits on new user accounts, please see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide